# Unique constraint violation on hibernate update to OneToMany collection

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-onetomany

I have the following entities:

```
@Entity
public class License  {

     // ...

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "license", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<Service> services = new HashSet<>();

    // ...

    protected void setServices(Set<String> services) {
        this.services.clear();
        if (services != null) {
            this.services.addAll(services.stream().map(s -> new Service(this, s)).collect(toSet()));
        }
    }
}

@Entity
@Table(uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(name = "UQ_lic_service", columnNames = { "license_id", "service" }))
public class Service {

    // ...

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "license_id", nullable = false)
    private License license;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 255)
    private String service;

    protected Service(License license, String service) {
        this.license = license;
        this.service = service;
    }
}
```

Now I need to update the `License` like:

```
    License license = getSomeExistingLicenseWithServices(...);
    // The existing license has two services "firstService", "secondService"
    HashSet<String> services = new HashSet<>();
    services.add("firstService");
    license.setServices(services);
    licenseRepository.save(license); // A spring-data-jpa-repository
```

Running this, I get the following exception:

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Eindeutiger Index oder Primärschlüssel verletzt: "UQ_LIC_SERVICE_INDEX_8 ON PUBLIC.SERVICE(LICENSE_ID, SERVICE) VALUES (1, 'firstService', 1)"
Unique index or primary key violation: "UQ_LIC_SERVICE_INDEX_8 ON PUBLIC.SERVICE(LICENSE_ID, SERVICE) VALUES (1, 'firstService', 1)"; SQL statement:
insert into service (id, lock_no, license_id, service) values (null, ?, ?, ?) [23505-196]
```

I expected all 'old' (='orphaned') `Service`s to become deleted, when I call `setServices` with a new `HashSet`. What I am doing wrong? TIA!

Comment: Did you get this to work?

Answer (score 4):

Just calling .clear() on the set may not be enough.  Likely its requiring an explicit call to  remove() on each component of the set before clearing it.

please try adding something like this before clearing the set to see if that solves the issue

```
this.services.forEach(service -> {licenseRepository.remove(service)});
```

Comment: Thank you. But I cannot do this. I need some cascading solution.

Answer (score 2):

Try to **clear** the list **before** setting the services:

```
license.getServices().clear();
```

And then

```
license.getServices.add("firstService");
licenseRepository.save(license);
```

**UPDATE**

To make this work, it is important to implement the `equals` and `hashCode` methods. I'm using apache commons lang library

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return new HashCodeBuilder().append(idService).toHashCode();
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (!(obj instanceof Service))
        return false;

    Service other = (Service) obj;

    return new EqualsBuilder()
            .append(this.idService, other.idService)
            .isEquals();
}
```

Comment: isn't the same clear before adding individually
lookup this http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#collections-value